# How to create an element in react and use aria-live as a custom hook on it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, accessibility, wcag

Is there a way to create a custom hook that will be able to create a component that will act as an announcer for aria-live to announce dynamic changes in applications?

Currently I'm using something like this:

```
export const useAnnouncer = () => {
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string | null>(null)

  const setAnnouncer = (m: string) => setMessage(m)

  const announcer = (
    <div className="sr-only" aria-live="polite" aria-atomic="true" >
      {message}
    </div>
  )
  
  return [announcer, setAnnouncer] as const
```

Actually, its works. But it's not my problem. Because right now wrapper for aria-live element is creating in component where hook is called.

for ex:

```
const Controls = () => {
  const [announcer, setAnnouncer] = useAnnouncer()

const handleClick = () => {
   setAnnouncer('test')
}

return (
  <div>
     {announcer}
     <nav><button onClick={(e: ButtonEvent) => handleClick(e, firstPage)}>test</button></nav>
   </div>
  )
}
```

I would like to avoid `{announcer}` in my jsx. Is it possible to create a wrapper for aria-live in `useAnnouncer` and only have setAnnouncer in the component to handle voice announcements?